# Writing to two file descriptors by only one operation

Tags: c, logging, file-descriptor

I want to implement logging functionality in C and log messages to both stdout and some file.
I would like to write something like fprintf(logout, "msg"); with somehow declared FILE* logout which will redirect strings to both stdout and some file. Is it possible?

Comment: Create your own function which outputs to both file and stdout.

Comment: I have functions like dump_MY_OWN_TYPE(TYPE) and would like to keep it like dump_MY_OWN_TYPE(TYPE, FILE* f) so I can call it them dump_MY_OWN_TYPE(TYPE, stdout) or dump_MY_OWN_TYPE(TYPE, logout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apparently want a `FILE`-like object that redirects its writes to two underlying `FILE`s (`stdout` and the log file). Standard C doesn't allow "subclassing" `FILE` objects in any way, so this is not possible in C. However, [GNU libc does](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Custom-Streams), so if your program is Linux-only, you can do that with some programming. As this is extremely non-portable, it is strongly recommended against.

A more portable way to achieve this is by writing to a pipe and creating a process or thread that reads from the pipe and writes to both underlying files. For example, assuming POSIX:

```
FILE *tee_file(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2)
{
  int fds[2];
  if (pipe(fds))
    return NULL;
  switch (fork()) {
    case 0: {
      char buf[512];
      int nread;
      FILE *r = fdopen(fds[0], "r");
      close(fds[1]);
      while ((nread = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, r)) {
        fwrite(buf, 1, nread, fp1);
        fwrite(buf, 1, nread, fp2);
      }
      _exit(0);
    }
    case -1:
      return NULL;
  }
  close(fds[0]);
  return fdopen(fds[1], "w");
}

/* after calling "fp = tee_file(fp1, fp2)", writes to fp
   end up in fp1 and fp2. */
```

Both approach add a good deal of complication to your program which should be justified by a very good reason. What you want is to use a logging framework that allows writing to multiple outputs (they all do), or write your own as outlined by H2CO3's answer.

Comment: Thanks. So standard C libraries doesn't allow it, and I need to get rid of that idea.

Comment: @DennisYurichev You can do it on Unix with a separate thread or process, see the edited answer, but it's still not a good idea unless you have a *really* good reason (such as supporting 3rd-party libs that only accept stdio objects as arguments).

Answer (score 3):

If this is on Linux, you can open a pipe to the `tee` command:

```
FILE *logout = popen("tee logfile", "w");
```

Comment: This is more or less what I use, but there's a bit of an issue that may or may not matter, depending on your use case: If you're running a program from the command line, the child process (your `tee` program) doesn't necessarily flush when it normally would, and more interestingly, when your program finishes the tee stays briefly open, meaning you don't get a prompt back _quit_ like you usually would (`tee` still writes to the screen for a bit, meaning your prompt gets buried in text).

All in all this approach "pretty much" works, and it's dirt simple so...

Comment: @scott_fakename I expect that `tee` uses stdio, with the default buffering. So if its standard output (which it inherits from your process) goes to a terminal, it will be line-buffered; if stdout is redirected to a file or pipe, it will be fully buffered. And I don't see any reason why `tee` would stay running much after it gets EOF on its input pipe; when it reads EOF, it should immediately flush all its buffers and exit.

Comment: I guess I should clarify; when I did this, i did a dup2 to make my program's stdout print to the `tee` process, and when the program closed the results I described took place. I didn't take too much care to look in to the exact mechanism for it, but that's what happened.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would make a difference, but we'd have to see the whole program to be sure. `tee` doesn't do anything but copy its input to all the outputs, and as soon as it receives EOF on the input it should flush and close all the outputs and exit.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make your very own logging function?

```
int log_fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *restrict fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stream, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);

    va_start(args, fmt);
    int n = vfprintf(stdout, fmt, args);
    // conceptually, rather `stderr`, please!
    va_end(args);

    return n;
}
```

Comment: because I have functions like dump_MY_OWN_TYPE(TYPE) and would like to keep it like dump_MY_OWN_TYPE(TYPE, FILE* f) so I can call it them dump_MY_OWN_TYPE(TYPE, stdout) or dump_MY_OWN_TYPE(TYPE, logout)

Comment: Imagine complex data type: struct cplx { float re; float im; }; Imagine dumper function takes both field and putting them into FILE: dump_cplx (struct cplx*, FILE*)

Comment: @DennisYurichev For that, it's particularly useful, if not necessary, to write your own function. `printf()` won't dump a custom struct for you.