# Can I redirect stdout to a file and the console at same time

Tags: redirect, console, posix, stdout, glibc

I have Linux application running on the Embedded board. I want to redirect stdout to a text file.
So I use below function

```
file = freopen("logs.txt","w",stdout);
```

After capturing I resume the console as

```
freopen("/dev/ttyAM0", "w", stdout);
```

My question is 
If I want to see my stdout on the console while capturing/redirecting it to file, Is it possible and if yes how to get this?

I also tried using dup2() API but not succeded.

Comment: Do you use glibc?

Comment: Yes, glibc-2.11.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing to two file descriptors by only one operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15716636/writing-to-two-file-descriptors-by-only-one-operation)